# Server Bindings for SSL Host Headers ip being set to 255.255.255.255

Tags: binding, ssl, iis-6, ip-address

I am using the below command, however the ip address of the binding is beng set to 255.255.255.255.

cscript.exe //nologo %systemdrive%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/your_website_identifier_here/SecureBindings “:9011:my.publicserver.com”

Anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want those "smart quotes" in the command.

Comment: @A.Agius: Use normal, proper quotes instead. Don't just remove them.

Comment: What do you mean by normal proper quotes? I'm using the normal double quote (the one that is found with the comma on the keyboard)

Comment: @A.Agius: No, you're not. `“` is not the same as `"`. Are you writing this command in Microsoft Word (which stylises quotes by default) or something?

Comment: @A.Agius: Write a double-quote for me here now.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, tried to write the double quote in the command promt directly and it work :0. Thanks a lot.